# I cant boot windows!

Tags: windows

Okay, I used an iso to put a file called artistx onto a disk, and then ran the installer. Artistx is apparently a different OS and downloaded Ubuntu 12.1.
So while trying to open Ubuntu, I got the error that gave me the low graphics card error. I did what was supposed to fix this, but my terminal wouldn't work with anything or do anything to fix this after searching the error. I got the error that my Harddrive was full and I had no memory left (for some reason artistx has my memory at 11GB/11GB even though I have a 650 GB Hard drive that Ubuntu won't use because it's HP or something). I don't have a windows recovery disk, and im not sure what else to do. When GRUB loads, it gives a list of Ubuntu, memory test, and a windows vista with sda 1 and sda 2 by them. I can email a picture if this to you if you'd like. If you could help in any way, it would be so helpful. Thank you!

Comment: According to this: http://artistx.org/blog/  *It doesn’t need to be installed, and boots directly into a running system without touching hard drives.*  Try their forum: http://www.artistx.org/smf/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try scrolling down to windows vista sda1 or sda2
and Press Enter?

One of those partition is vista, the other is Vista Recovery Utility.
In my computer sda1 is vista and sd2 is the recovery.

You can also access the Vista Recovery Utility when you turn on the computer from
HP bios Screen. In mines you type F11 but yours may  be different.

If you want revert to boot in windows follow this instructions from Microsoft 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392 
from the recovery utility console.

You will have to do some disk cleaning, afterwards to recover the space.